# CMake problem: could not find any instance of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, sdk

**What I want to do**

I got a source SDK file folder which contains all the files needed to create a project (or .sln), including a CMakeLists. And then I tried to use CMake to build a solution file. And this image below is the guide for how to get this SDK started.

[SDK instruction guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8yhh.png)

**What I did**

1. Open Visual Studio 2019 (The CMake module have been installed).
2. Open the SDK file folder with VS2019.
3. Click "Tools" and open Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.4.2.
4. Type:

   ```
   mkdir build
   cd build
   cmake -G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..
   ```

**Problem**

And I met the problem below:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  Generator 

Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/StructureSDK-CrossPlatform-0.7.3-ROS/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please also add the CMakeOutput.log file to the question. Your problem might be that the visual studio installation path is not added to environmental variables.

Comment: Thank you! I have added VS installation path to environmental variables but it still doesn't work. And the CMakeOutput.log is: **The system is: Windows - 10.0.18362 - AMD64**

Comment: Thank you Narra, my problem has been solved. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project): Generator

Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

indicates that you probably do not have **Visual Studio 2017** installed, or at least, not installed correctly. If you want CMake to use **Visual Studio 2019** instead, which it appears you have installed, you should use the following `cmake` command instead:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 ..
```

Visual Studio 15 2017 and Visual Studio 16 2019 provide different compile suites, so you must be sure to use the correct *version*.

Note, your instructions for setting up the SDK indicate that the SDK was tested on Visual Studio 2017. So, to avoid other potential issues you may encounter with Visual Studio 2019, I suggest downloading and installing Visual Studio 2017 instead. Then, simply following the instructions should work without errors.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried the VS2019 `cmake` command:

`cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 ..`

And it works!!! Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem when connecting to a windows build node from Jenkins via ssh.

What I was able to verify is that through the ssh connection running bash or windows cmd shell `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"` would return no results.

However when running from local bash or cmd shell on the build node vswhere would return all the expected information.

After carefully comparing the differences in the two sets of environment variables ssh connection vs local setting ProgramData resulted in vswhere returning the expected results and CMake could find all installed Visual Studio instances.

In cmd shell

```
set ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
```

In .bashrc

```
export ProgramData='C:\ProgramData'
```

See also:

- [Please point to vswhere.exe in Visual Studio toolchain docs](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22256)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. I had version 16.9.3 installed of vs2019. I fixed the issue by running the vs installer. I clicked modify, the installer downloaded and installed 16.9.4, and after reboot cmake could properly detect that vs2019 was installed.

Note: When clicking modify, make sure "Visual C++ tools for CMake" is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I encountered when I was following instructions online. After calling

```
cmake ".." -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -DXMRIG_DEPS=c:\xmrig-deps\msvc2019\x64
```

I got an error saying VS16 is not installed. I removed the entire folder, restarted the process and replaced the `-G` switch option with `Visual Studio 17 2022` and it started (although mentioning some deprecation warnings):

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -DXMRIG_DEPS=c:\xmrig-deps\msvc2019\x64
```

Answer (score -2):

For me it works with Visual Studio 2022.

You should use an IDE like Visual Studio Code, android studio doesn't work and/or use this line:

```
flutter config --enable-windows-desktop.
```

Have an nice day